# Javascript add a variable in this JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following `var x = "bob"`
and want to put var x value into "something"

```
var request = {
    "id":"2",
    "number":"12345",
    "params":[{
        "name":"bob",
        "message":"hi"
    }],
    "something": "${x}"
 }
```

I am new to JS and NodeJS and am stumped on how to easily do this.

Comment: What do you mean put x into something?  It looks like `request.something` already has a value of `"${x}"` which makes it seem like you want to format that string with the value in 'x' using backtick formatting.  Can you show what you want the result to look like?

Comment: console.log(request)  should look like  {"id":"2","number":"12345","params":[{"name":"bob","message":"hi"}],"something": "bob"}

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is

```
request.something = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the key using dot(`.`) or square notation`[]`

```js
var x = "bob"
var request = {
  "id": "2",
  "number": "12345",
  "params": [{
    "name": "bob",
    "message": "hi"
  }],
  "something": "${x}"
}
request.something = x;
console.log(request)
```

Comment: let me clarify.    Var request = {
  "id": "2",
  "number": "12345",
  "params": [{
    "name": "bob",
    "message": "hi"
  }],
  "something": I want to put var x here
}

Comment: @SamelK you want to replace the key or value?

Comment: correct want to replace the value of "something".  console.log(request) would print {
  "id": "2",
  "number": "12345",
  "params": [{
    "name": "bob",
    "message": "hi"
  }],
  "something": "bob"}

Answer (score 0):

you must use (dot) to change a javascript Object

```
var x = 'bob';

request.something = x;
```